# get Element using PostMessage

Tags: javascript, html

It's Possible to get : "MyTextTarget" in div in: domain2/file.html from this iframe using javascript postMessage ?

```
<div class="c1">
    <iframe name="name1" id="name1" src="http://domain/file.html" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

in **domain/file.html** :

```
<div class="c2_  " >
    MyTextTarget
</div>
```